# Add codec DA7213 to Yocto image

Tags: audio, yocto, codec, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am new to yocto, and i'd like to add the support of the DA7213 codec.

I went ahead and activated it in menuconfig using `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`

But after building `bitbake fsl-image-gui` and flashing the built image, i cannot seem to find the DA7213 module, in linux.

I used lsmod and dmesg, but without any success.

When i launch alsamixer, i cannot find da7213 there also.

NB : I'm using the HardKnott release of yocto

Comment: After doing menuconfig, have you also saved the resulting `.config` file (or the differences compared to the original), and added it to your recipe?

Comment: I saved my differences in .config, but how do i add it to my recipe?